# tagnameで取得した要素がSELECTではなくBODYになる

Tags: javascript, html

プルダウン（selectタグ）に対して `b` を取得していますので `b = SELECT` となって欲しいものの、どういうわけか `b = BODY` となってしまう場合があります。

以下ページで `activeElement` の仕様を確認すると次のような記載がありました。

[Document.activeElement - Web API | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement)

> どの要素にフォーカスが当たるかは、プラットフォームやブラウザーの現在の設定によって異なります。例えば、 macOS システムでは通常、既定では、テキスト入力要素以外の要素はフォーカスされません。

macOSは使用しておらず、WindowsとChromeの環境で `b = BODY` が発生するのですが原因分かる方いらっしゃいますでしょうか。

```
var a = document.activeElement;
var b = a.tagName.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

質問文からよく読み取れないのですが、もしかして**focus**（フォーカス）と**select**（選択）を混同していたりしませんか？
例えば `Tab`キーを押してフォーカスを移動した場合にどこに飛びますか？ `Shift + Tab` で`<select>`要素に戻りますか？ `↑`キー `↓`キーでプルダウンの選択内容は更新されますか？ そうでなく画面がスクロールしたりしませんか？

- [`HTMLElement.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus)
- [`<select>`: HTML 選択要素](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select)

などのページでフォーカスの挙動について確認してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば Tabキーを押してフォーカスを移動した場合にどこに飛びますか？ Shift + Tab で<select>要素に戻りますか？→Tabキーを押下でselectに移動でき、Shift + Tabでselcectに戻ります。

Comment: <select>要素に戻りますか？ ↑キー ↓キーでプルダウンの選択内容は更新されますか？ そうでなく画面がスクロールしたりしませんか？→プルダウンの選択内容が更新され、画面がスクロールはされないです。

Comment: 質問文からよく読み取れないのですが、もしかしてfocus（フォーカス）とselect（選択）を混同していたりしませんか？→こちら分かりにくくて申し訳ありませんでした。プルダウン（selectタグ）の選択肢を選択した時にソース上にブレークポイントを設置し処理が止まるようにしており、その際にtagnameで取得している要素のタグ名を確認するとbodyの場合とselectの場合がありこれが何が原因でタグ名が変わるのかわからないといった状況です。